# Connecting to AWS KMS through VPCE using DotNet

Tags: c#, amazon-kms

I am trying to figure out how to connect to AWS KMS using the vpce url using dot net C#. I am able to connect using java. Same api is not available in dot net. Can some one help me find a solution on it.

```
AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(myCredentialProvider)
                    .withEndpointConfiguration((new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("vpce-01579256a821c8130-e9awdl5a.kms.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com","us-east-1"))).build();
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how to create a client with vpce, but if you set enableDnsHostnames and enableDnsSupport attribute of the VPC to true, you can use the regional endpoint kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and don't have to specify the DNS name of the VPCE.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-private-dns

Comment: Solved by using a proxy settings.